# Pdf version 1.7 returning PdfName.DA to be null in PDFDictionary in itext2

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to get the font size of acroField of a pdf version 1.7.
I am using this code to get font size of AcroField of PDF.
But pdf Dictionary does not contains the key (PdfName.DA).
When I am accesing pdfObject from PdfDictionary for PdfName.DA, I am getting null.
My code is

```
     final AcroFields.Item item = acroFields.getFieldItem(fieldName);

     ArrayList list =null;
     list = item.merged;
     if (list != null) 
            {
               for (final Iterator it1 = list.iterator(); it1.hasNext();) 
                 {
                    final PdfDictionary itemDict = (PdfDictionary) it1.next();
                    final PdfObject da = itemDict.get(PdfName.DA);
                    System.out.println(da); //da coming null.
                 }
             }
```

I am using jar "itext-2.1.7.jar"

Above code works fine for PDF With version 1.6.But it is not working well for version 1.7 of PDF.

The link for the PDF is "http://www.mediafire.com/view/riuajytszavbq77/JanWebinar013014.pdf"

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think the "DA" key should be there? The PDF specification clearly states that the DA key is in the "Additional entries common to all fields containing variable text". The fields in your PDF file doen't appear to have variable text (text entered by the user for example).

As such the "DA" key is optional and you should be prepared to accept it isn't there.

Comment: Thanks @David. My PDF contains interactive links as a form field.I am not able to manipulate these links as they are showing type "1" i.e of image. Is there any way to find the type of link.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. Judging by your code (I'm not a java expert) you know how to get to the form element dictionary in the file; that should give you all information you need no?

Comment: @David.My PDF has interactive links.But acroFields.getFieldType() method return 1 for image and this link field both.I just want to know how to test whether it is image or interactive link.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that field type means it's a pushbutton. Which is correct if I think of your file. To know whether you're talking about an image or a link, you'd have to look at the actual appearance of the field (which objects it uses to draw itself). Because all fields in your document are in fact "links" in the sense that you can click them to make something happen...